# Is there any offline docs for chrome extension development?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am learning to develop a chrome extension, but I can't access the official site of chrome extension development from China, you know, for some reasons. Is there any way or place I can get the latest docs? Though I can find some docs translated from the official docs, they are either incomplete or outdated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use an app like HTTrack to download the site via VPN? I did so myself because the local copy is so much faster.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm , but the biggest problem is that I don't have any VPN connection.  :(  Could you please share your copies to me via github or some other ways.

Comment: Here's [my copy](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/642338d925c66973997d9d5bf0df2e5020201205102519/cf0cfd). It doesn't contain the most recent changes to chrome.declarativeNetRequest though.